# SCONS to Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, scons

I got a project, source code, etc, using SCONS. Could you recommend tools/ways to convert or integrate it in a Visual Studio C command line project ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi this may be usefull http://www.scons.org/wiki/IDEIntegration#head-a0b9e629986abc8528bdd599bac43a22cd161bf4

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you explained what is behind the link and how it would help.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this doesn't directly answer your question but I'd reconsider against using SCONS. Native Visual Studio projects have too many advantages such as being able to use Incredibuild, Visual Assist et c.

Instead you might want to look at XPJ:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xpj/

What it does is generates a vcproj from an XML file, which can also be used to generate a SCONS project if absolutely necessary.

If you are not convinced, you can custom command line project option in Visual Studio and have it invoke the SCONS build.